# Image with controls

Tags: ios, user-interface

I would like a window to slide in from the side whenever the user hits a button on the bar of my app.
I would like that "window" to be semi transparent and have controls like other images that actually use as buttons, UILabels and text fields.
What would be a good way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "*and have controls like other images that actually use as buttons, UILabels and text fields*", but I'll give it a shot.

The semitransparent window with controls should be something like this:

> - UIView - backgroundColor = clearColor [parent view]
>
>   - UIView - alpha = 0.5 [transparent view]
>   - controls - buttons, labels, etc

Basically, this layout will give you a transparent background view and visible controls. Just make sure that your controls have the same parent [the *parent view*] as the *transparent view*.

To slide in / out you can use:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

// move the parent view here

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can achieve what you want by simply :

- creating your main view controller
- creating separate UIView or UIViewController and setting its frame.origin parameters to hide it in left/right/top/bottom

Manage transparency in a way that DarkByte briefly explained.
[example slidingView.alpha = 0.5;]

To animate the "sliding" I would rather use:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration 
                      delay:wait
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     /*Parameter changing code goes heare, for example: */ 
                     view.frame.origin.x = newX; 
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     /*Code which will be executed AFTER the animation goes heare*/
                 }];
```

I think it's easy to use and setting code to be executed after animation is very convenient.